# Finding universal covers through homotopy equivalence

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

In general, if one knows the universal cover of a space, how does one find the universal cover of a homotopy equivalent space? Is there a systematic way to do this? If not, are there certain techniques in practice?
Does it become easier if 1 space is a deformation retract of the other?

We have from Exercise 8 in Section 1.3 in Hatcher that homotopy equivalent spaces have homotopy equivalent universal covers.
But I don't know if this helps in practice to find a universal cover.

(I'd really appreciate if you could give a few examples of finding the universal cover by finding the universal cover of a deformation retract.)

Comment: Hints: $i)$ The pullback of a covering map is a covering map. $ii)$ A covering space is universal if and only if it is simply connected (in Hatcher's definitions). $iii)$ You need to check that the properties a space is required to have to admit a universal cover are homotopy type invariants (for instance, a homotopy equivalence induces a bijection on path components).

Comment: Thank you for the response! I wasn't asking how to show that homotopy equivalent spaces have homotopy equivalent universal covers though. I am aware of this. I am asking if there is a way to use this knowledge (or other things) to construct a universal cover for a space, given a universal cover for a homotopy equivalent one.

Comment: Tyrone understood this (as far as I can tell), the hints are precisely for that purpose (in particular, pay close attention to hint i) )

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent and $\rho\colon U \to Y$ is a universal cover. What Tyrone is hinting at is that if $f\colon X \to Y$ is a homotopy equivalence then $f^*U$ is a universal cover of $X$.

Here is a simple example:

We know the universal cover of $S^1$ is $\mathbb{R}$, and we can take the covering map $exp\colon \mathbb{R}\to S^1$ given by $exp(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$. Now consider the open annulus $A = \{ z\in \mathbb{C}\mid \frac{1}{2} < |z| < \frac{3}{2} \}$, which is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ via the inclusion $\iota \colon S^1 \hookrightarrow A$ and the normalization map $\eta\colon A \to S^1$ given by $\eta(z) = \frac{z}{|z|}$.

Consider the pullback

$$ \eta^*(\mathbb{R}) = \{ (z, t) \in A \times \mathbb{R}\mid \eta(z) = exp(t)\}. $$

As I mentioned above this is a universal cover of $A$, and in this particular case you can show that the map $\Phi\colon \eta^*(\mathbb{R}) \to  (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2})\times\mathbb{R}$ given by $\Phi(z, t) = (|z|, t)$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you. Are there useful techniques to realize whatever construction you get by f\*U as a "familiar" space (say as a CW complex)? Or would one usually write down set-theoretically "f\*U = ..." as you have, and then deal with realizing it as a CW complex as a separate problem?

Comment: Also, sorry, I know this should be obvious, but what is $\eta$\* explicitly as a map?

Comment: Identifying a convenient description of $f^*U$ typically depends on the situation, but it's usually a good idea to start with the definition of the pull-back like I wrote down. The covering map $\eta^*(\mathbb{R}) \to A$ is $(z, t) \mapsto z$.